# Fetching JPA @OneToMany collection returns empty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying out some [EJB3 in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/ejb-3-in-action-second-edition) examples using Glassfish4 (EclipseLink) + JavaDB. So I have the below relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEMS")
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long itemId;
    ...
    private List<Bid> bids= new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @Column(name="ITEM_ID")
    public Long getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(Long itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="item",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)   
    @JoinColumn(name="BID_ITEM_ID",referencedColumnName="ITEM_ID")
    public List<Bid> getBids() {
        return bids;
    }

    public void setBids(List<Bid> bids) {
        this.bids = bids;
    }   
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BIDS")
public class Bid implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ...   
    private Item item;    
    ...

    @Id
    @Column(name="BID_ID")
    public Long getBidId() {
        return bidId;
    }

    public void setBidId(Long bidId) {
        this.bidId = bidId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BID_ITEM_ID",referencedColumnName="ITEM_ID")
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }    
    ...        
}
```

Now when fetching an Item like

```
@Override
public List<Bid> getBidsForItem(long itemId) {
    Item item = em.find(Item.class, itemId); // em -> Entity manager
    return item.getBids();
}
```

the `item.getBids()` returns an empty list (size = 0, not null). What changes should be done to get Bids for the given Item?

**EDIT:**
  After enabling query logging as suggested in the comments

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

I notice that Queries are listed for insert statements but NO query is listed corresponding to `em.find(Item.class, itemId)`.

**EDIT 2 (ANSWER):**
The problem was in my addBids() stateless bean function to which I was passing an Item object. This meant the Item Object is never in persistent context. The right way is to

1. pass the itemId
2. find the Item entity with entity manager find() method. This ensures that the Item object is in persistence context.
3. add bid object to item and item to bid
4. call entity manager persist() on Bid.

Corrected addBids() method:

```
public Bid addBids(Date bidDate, Double bidPrice, long itemId, String bidder) {  
        Item item = em.find(Item.class, itemId);  
        Bid bid = new Bid(bidDate, bidPrice, item, bidder);  
        item.getBids().add(bid);  
        em.persist(bid);  
        return bid;  
}
```

Thanks to @Chris for pointing out.

Comment: Does the database contain the appropriate data?

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox - yes. Say Item with ITEM_ID= 100 has two Bids with BID_ID (5000, 5001) and BID_ITEM_ID=100.

Comment: Why don't you watch the executed SQL queries (google how to enable query logging in EclipseLink)? Are you sure you use the correct DB or so...?

Comment: Refresh the Item by calling em.refresh(item);.  If it then has bids, make sure you are maintaining both sides of your bi-directional relationship.  Every time you add an item to a bid, you must add the bid to the item's list of bids

Comment: @Chris With em.refresh(item) it worked. But the function List<Bid> getBidsForItem() is stateless bean method. I am adding Bids to the list as part of another stateless bean method. How to realize your suggestion "Every time you add an item to a bid, you must add the bid to the item's list of bids" then?

Comment: @KiranMohan like it is described here (add the Bid to the Item's list and set the Item in the Bid): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092198/cascade-persist-error-with-jpa-and-eclipselink-on-manytoone-relationship/20093000#20093000

Comment: I suggest you take your 2nd edit and make it an answer to this question. This specific problem got me stuck for over 3 hours, and it may help a lot of folks that directly search for an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try instantiating a `ArrayList<Bid>` and assigning it to the `List<Bid>` declaration.

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="item")
  protected List<Bid> bids = new ArrayList<Bid>();
```

Comment: its done that way. Note that I mentioned the result list size is 0 and the list reference is not null. Without assigning an ArrayList I was getting null pointer exception.

Comment: @KiranMohan Your mapping looks correct, maybe post the whole entity?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
public class Item{
private List<Bid> bids= new ArrayList<>();
public void setBids(List<Bid> bids) {
    for (Bid bid : bids) {
        bid.setItem(this);
    }
    this.bids = bids;
}
```

}

Here you are freeing the client to make the relationship. Do the otherway round in Bid class also. But make sure you won't end up with infinite to and fro method calls.
And its a good approach to provide an add and remove method. 
like :- `public class Item{
    private List<Bid> bids= new ArrayList<>();
    public void addBid(Bid bid) {
        bid.setItem(this);
        this.bids.add(bids);
    }
}`